# Easy API for retrieving width and height when using metadata-extractor

Tags: java, image-processing, metadata-extractor

I am using the excellent [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) library. It is very good for retrieving detailed metadata from many different image formats.

However, for a project i am only interested in extracting "common image metadata" (like width and height). In this use case the API is quiet verbose AFIAK.

I am looking for a convenience API like:

```
final MetadataWrapper md = MetadataWrapper.readMetadata(file);
FileType type = md.getFileType();
int width = md.getWidth();
int height = md.getHeight();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

If you know exactly what metadata you need, you're probably best off writing a small wrapper around metadata-extractor that checks for specific types of directory, and tests them for given tags.

The concept of 'width' can be specified in many different tags. metadata-extractor doesn't provide any abstraction over these, though there is an [issue discussing the idea](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/10). It'll be tricky to implement robustly.

Comment: Thanks! An up vote for the link, really helpful discussion and indeed where I am looking for.

Comment: I think a general approach to retrieving common metadata like width and height would be great. But after reading the discussion (link from above) I understand the problem. The only question is whether you can do it better yourself. I now have several checks in my application for DirectoryType and then fetch the metadata I want. This is always a bit cumbersome, since one always overlooks any exotics such as HEIC images and then subsequently incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give the Java7 BufferedImage a try?
It contains the convenient methods `getHeight`, `getWidth` and `getType`.

More info here: [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

Comment: Because I need to process a large number of large files (so performance is important) and (most important) metadata-extractor supports much more image formats

Comment: Point taken, extended & improved my answer.